# Set Google+ Profile Picture for Google Apps for Business Users

Tags: google-api, google-plus

We have company pictures that we would like to set as everyone's profile pictures. We're able to set their directory/contact profile picture with no real issues, however, we can't figure out how to change their Google+ profile picture.

Is there any way to change their profile pictures with the Google+ API? Or without using Google+ (aside from logging into every account :P )

I've done a general search here on stack and Google, but could only find old sources or people wanting to *get* profile pictures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google+ Domains API [does not have a method for updating people](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/api/people). If you would like one please [open a feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/list).